# How to change the size of main Tkinter window in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label set at a certain size but when I run my program, the main window is not large enough to see the entire label.
How do I increase the size of the main window?  I have tried different options but I am not having any luck.

```
import win32com.client
import os
# import threading # use the Timer
import tkinter

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

class myGUI:

    def timer(self):

        import pythoncom       
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()  

        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) 



        messages = inbox.Items
        message = messages.GetLast()
        body_content = message.Subject # can be Body, To, REcipients, Sender, etc


        self.answer_label['text'] = (body_content) # orginally used body_content.encode("utf-8") to fixed character encoding issue


        self.master.after(20, self.timer) # after needs to be called from an existing widget such as master
                                         # In this case, the after method is used to refresh the e-mails instead of threading

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("CheckStat")


        self.answer_label = Label(master, text='', fg="light green", bg="dark green", font="Helvetica 16 bold italic")
        self.answer_label.place(height=100, width=600)

        self.timer()


root = Tk()
my_gui = myGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you have to use the `.place()` manager? (You probably don't) `.place()` ignores boundaries and places relatively, you probably want to use the other window managers (`.grid()` and `.pack()`, though the former will benefit you more to learn and save some headache- though note that these two **cannot** be used in the same container (rather, Tk will try to resolve them for the rest of our Sun's lifetime)).

Comment: No, I don't have to use .place.  I originally chose that because I thought it would give me more control.

Comment: It may give slightly more control, but you don't want more control. You want things to "just work" without needing to be 100% explicit, knowing you can always be more explicit- if `.grid()` can't give you exactly what you want, you can move to `.place()` for that specific thing. But `.grid()` can probably give you exactly what you want in 60% of circumstances, `.pack()` will take care of 99% of the rest. `.place()` is useful when things need to be positioned relative to the whole window or other elements, but not in a way `.grid()` handles, and also is useful for overlapping elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `pack` or `grid` instead of `place`, the window will automatically grow or shrink to fit the contents of the label. `place` is best used very sparingly, if at all.

If you want to use `place`, you can give the window an explicit size with the `geometry` method of the root window.

For example, to make the root window be 600x100, you should add this line:

```
root.geometry("600x100")
```

Comment: I was wondering about the root.geometry().  I have tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Prox: It definitely does something. It forces the size of the root window to the specified size.